# how do i properly format this in vba

Tags: excel, colors, cell, vba

This works fine but i'm trying to learn how to properly format this more like a normal function vs. what xls macro generated code looks like. Here i'm filtering for all rows that have yellow in this column.

```
sheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
```

This does not work

```
sheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter(1,RGB(255,255,0),xlFilterCellColor)
```

nor does this

```
sheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter(1,RGB(255,255,0),xlFilterCellColor,,)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't put parenthesis around a parameter list unless you are returning a value.

```
sheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, RGB(255,255,0), xlFilterCellColor
```

The parameter values **must** be in the 'normal' order that they are expected. If you plan to add them in 'out-of-order' then naming the parameters puts the correct value in the correct parameter.

```
sheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Operator:=xlFilterCellColor, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), field:=1
```

Some VBA functions return a usefull value. In these cases, use parenthesis on the parameter list.

```
dim r as variant
r = sheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter(1, RGB(255,255,0), xlFilterCellColor)
debug.print r
```

In this case, r is True whether the .AutoFilter shows records or not.

Comment: ok...that explains the compile/run time error (expected =) and also the fact that you can put them out of order but named explains why they are named when generated by a macro. Thanks so much.

Comment: Note that your RGB function is returning a long integer (e.g. 65535) into the Criteria1 parameter and as such, requires parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple using sub procedure.

```
Sub test()
    myFilter Sheet1.UsedRange, 1, RGB(255, 255, 0)
End Sub


Sub myFilter(rng As Range, i As Integer, color As Long)
rng.AutoFilter field:=i, Criteria1:=color, Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
End Sub
```